# Using directional markers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, markers

I'm a QGIS neophyte and I'm looking for a little help.  I'm trying to integrate QGIs into my forensic investigation practice, with regard to investigating and processing accident scenes.  I take a fairly high volume of photos and in some cases, it would be helpful to add a point layer to a QGIS map of the accident scene, which depicts where I took specific photos.

I'd like for the map to display the photo number, and align to the specific place the photo was taken from based on the photos EXIF data, including GPS coordinates, bearing, etc.,and to point, generally, in the direction the photo was taken, derived from the bearing.

The database I use to manage my images can separate out the EXIF positioning data.

What I'd love to be able to do is to have a Triangle or other marker that is positioned at the appropriate Lat and Long positions, facing the correct bearing, and labled with the appropriate photo number...

I doubt I'm the only person who would find this helpful.  Any ideas on where to look for explanations or tutorials on similar issues?

Comment: To which format is your database able to export EXIF tags? Would it fit your needs to visualize eg a CSV file with GPS coordinates and EXIF tags with rotated symbols? It would be helpful to have an example of the data your database would provide.

Comment: The export would contain the assigned photo number, lat,long & bearing, in CSV format...

Comment: That is exactly what you need to go the way mapBaker described in his answer below. My answer would be very similar so it can be omitted. Or do you miss something?

Answer (score 3):

If you can get your data into a CSV, with the LAT, LON, and bearing, you can use all of that to drive the symbols of your photos.

Turning the CSV into a spatial table is done by simply using QGIS > Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer, pointing to your LAT/LON columns, and specify (i'm guessing) WGS84 as the coordinate system of the points.

Then once your points are on the map, you can use the basic symbol renderer to apply your desired arrow

Then, mostly all settings in QGIS can be data driven, including the angle the photo / arrow symbol point - so as long as your bearing came across in your CSV, you can simply point your 'angle' setting to that field:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a pretty good solution... Please let us know how you managed to perform it (if so)!

Comment: @JayG great- keep in touch and let us know if it works!